# expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

i'am getting that erreur 
on those lines (127 / 130 / 138)
i don't know what is exactly wrong with the code but i guess it's a syntaxe erreur or something like that ??
any help with that
the same code works fine in react-script 1.1.0
ps i'm using react-script 3.0.0

```
handleDBReponse(response) {
    const appointments = response;
    const today = moment().startOf("day"); //start of today 12 am
    const initialSchedule = {};
    initialSchedule[today.format("YYYY-DD-MM")] = true;
    const schedule = !appointments.length
      ? initialSchedule
      : appointments.reduce((currentSchedule, appointment) => {
          const { slot_date, slot_time } = appointment;
          const dateString = moment(slot_date, "YYYY-DD-MM").format(
            "YYYY-DD-MM"
          );
       !currentSchedule[slot_date] //line 127
            ? (currentSchedule[dateString] = Array(8).fill(false)) 
            : null;
          Array.isArray(currentSchedule[dateString]) //line130

            ? (currentSchedule[dateString][slot_time] = true)
            : null;
          return currentSchedule;
        }
        , initialSchedule);

    for (let day in schedule) {
      let slots = schedule[day];  //138
      slots.length
        ? slots.every(slot => slot === true)
          ? (schedule[day] = true)
          : null
        : null;
    }
```

Comment: Probably this is linting error and not the compilation error.

Comment: @VikashSingh so what should i do ?

Comment: Just disable the linting or improve your code quality.

Comment: @VikashSingh still the same issue :/

Answer (score 1):

Let's take the following as an example:

```
currentSchedule[slot_date] ?
  (currentSchedule[dateString] = Array(8).fill(false)) 
  : null;
```

lint is expecting something like:

```
currentSchedule[dateString] = currentSchedule[slot_date] ?
  (Array(8).fill(false)) 
  : null;
```